# multipling in php echo statement

Tags: php, mysql, html, math

I have the following echo statement:

```
   <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Total Price: $<?php echo $course_priceFinal; ?></label><br><br>
```

I would like the value `$course_priceFinal`multiplies by the following if available

```
 $coupon
where     $coupon = $_GET['crs_coupon'];
```

In other words, the value of $course_priceFinal would be like

```
$course_priceFinal = $course_priceFinal - $course_priceFinal x ($coupon/100);
$coupon is a value between 5 and 15 but that value can change
```

sorry i would want course final to take the value of this input rather than the $coupon directly because user are also be to change the value of the input so i cant just rely on what was posted `<input type="text" name="name" class="email form-control" placeholder="Coupon Code" value=<?php echo $coupon; ?>>` –

Comment: that's issue. I am a bit clueless on how to approach this

Comment: simply do a `if` statement to check if you you have `$coupen isset` and than manipulate the  `$course_priceFinal`. By the way `$course_priceFinal = $course_priceFinal - x $course_priceFinal x ($coupon/100);` this calculation does make sense ?

Comment: i meant $course_priceFinal = $course_priceFinal -  ($course_priceFinal x ($coupon/100));

Comment: Suggestion: your `$coupon` variable should be cast to a numeric type if you're going to do math operations on it.

Comment: my knowledge is admitetly low, how would i cast, it and would truly appreciate an example. i think were on the right path

Comment: sorry i would want course final to take the value of this input rather than the $coupon directly because user are also be to change the value of the input so i cant just rely on what was posted       <input type="text" name="name" class="email form-control" placeholder="Coupon Code" value=<?php echo $coupon; ?>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<!-- Coupon Code-->
<input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="email form-control" placeholder="Coupon Code" value=<?php echo $coupon; ?>>

<!-- Price Final -->
<input type="text" name="course_pricefinal" class="email form-control" placeholder="Course Price Final" value=<?php echo $course_priceFinal; ?>>
```

PHP

```
// Note the (int). This is how you cast a variable.
$coupon = isset($_POST['coupon_code']) ? (int)$_POST['coupon_code'] : '';
```

Now calculation

```
$course_priceFinal = $_POST['course_pricefinal']; // Take value from form.
```

Now check if we have any numeric value in $coupon it means user has provided some coupen

```
if(is_int($coupon)
{
    $course_priceFinal = $course_priceFinal - ($course_priceFinal x ($coupon/100));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I do it so that the variable in the URL is hidden. In the sense that for security reason someone can change change the coupon variable in the url to maybe 100, and where I do not want the post to be visible to the public

Comment: your form method id `POST` then how can you see the url ?